# '23/02/2011 12:34:56' is not valid date and time

Tags: delphi

In my code I am facing a problem. Example code:

```
var 
    d1: tdatetime
begin
    d1 := strtodatetime('23/02/2011 12:34:56');
end;
```

but it's giving the error:

> '23/02/2011 12:34:56' is not valid
>   date and time

What's wrong with what I am doing?

Comment: Looks like a locale issue: that's a valid UK date but not US date, for example.

Comment: I'd put an warning on the "StrToDate[Time]" function[s]: *"Warning, this function depends on the locale and might fail miserably on other computers. That's why you should never use string to enter, edit or store a date, never!"*.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

the [StrToDateTime](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/SysUtils.StrToDateTime) function uses the [`ShortDateFormat`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/SysUtils.ShortDateFormat) and [`DateSeparator`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/SysUtils.DateSeparator) to convert the date part and the [`LongTimeFormat`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/SysUtils.LongTimeFormat) and [`TimeSeparator`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/SysUtils.TimeSeparator) to the time part. so you string must match with theses variables to convert the string to TDateTime. instead you can use the StrToDateTime with the [`TFormatSettings`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/SysUtils.TFormatSettings) parameter, to parse you string.

```
 function StrToDateTime(const S: string; const FormatSettings: TFormatSettings): TDateTime;
```

check this sample

```
Var
StrDate : string;
Fmt     : TFormatSettings;
dt      : TDateTime;
begin
fmt.ShortDateFormat:='dd/mm/yyyy';
fmt.DateSeparator  :='/';
fmt.LongTimeFormat :='hh:nn:ss';
fmt.TimeSeparator  :=':';
StrDate:='23/02/2011 12:34:56';
dt:=StrToDateTime(StrDate,Fmt);
```

Comment: Why use `nn` in `LongTimeFormat` instead of `mm` for minutes?

Comment: Because _nn_ means minutes and _mm_  means months.

Answer (score 10):

Using [VarToDateTime](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE3/en/System.Variants.VarToDateTime) might be a lot simpler and it just works out of the box:

```
uses Variants;

newDateTime := VarToDateTime('23/02/2011 12:34:56');
```

Comment: If date-time format is something like "06. okt. 2015", then even StrToDateTime(DateTimeToStr(Now)) fails. But VarToDateTime (instead of StrToDateTime) works fine. It seems to be best option.

Answer (score 2):

This is caused by the date/time format in your code not matching the date/time format for your locale settings.

From the docs (D2009):

> The S parameter must use the current
>   locale's date/time format. In the US,
>   this is commonly MM/DD/YY HH:MM:SS
>   format. Specifying AM or PM as part of
>   the time is optional, as are the
>   seconds. Use 24-hour time (7:45 PM is
>   entered as 19:45, for example) if AM
>   or PM is not specified.

If you are using an older Delphi, StrToDateTime may require a specific format. From the docs (D5 in this case):

> The S parameter must be in the
>   MM/DD/YY HH:MM:SS format. Specifying
>   AM or PM as part of the time is
>   optional, as are the seconds. Use
>   24-hour time (7:45 PM is entered as
>   19:45, for example) if AM or PM is not
>   specified.