# Crash in Delphi function - StrToDateTime

Tags: delphi, date

Who can to advice in my problem. 
I set date format as 'JUL/12 - 12 15:35', but when using StrToDateTime then give EConvertError.

What can I do with this format which contains 2 - date separator ?

---

Use next code

```
    function LocaleFormatStrToDateTime(const S: string): TDateTime;
        var
          LFormatSettings: TFormatSettings;
        begin
          LFormatSettings := GetLocaleFormatSettings(LOCALE_SYSTEM_DEFAULT);
          LFormatSettings.ShortTimeFormat := FormatSettings.ShortTimeFormat;
          LFormatSettings.TimeSeparator := FormatSettings.TimeSeparator;
          Result := StrToDateTime(S, LFormatSettings);
        end;


----------
```

**

> the best solution is use jvDateUtil.StrToDate*

**

Comment: Please provide also an example value of the `S` parameter that you're using to call this function

Comment: Where exactly is that date format used? It's none of the standard formats from anywhere (at least I've never run across it, and it's not anything I can set in Control Panel for a date/time format).

Comment: You, are right about standard formats. 
This is my custom format

Comment: Please see the edit to my original answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably the string you're trying to convert is not compatible with the default system format. Taking a look at the [method signature and description](http://www.delphibasics.co.uk/RTL.asp?Name=StrToDateTime) reveals that you can override it to suit your needs, see an example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3330679/23-02-2011-123456-is-not-valid-date-and-time).

It would be helpful if you posted a piece of the code you have so far, maybe you overlooked something.

---

**EDIT**

I've missed the fact that your're using a complex format, including multiple separators for the date, which I'm not sure that are supported in delphi.

I guess that in this case you could split your string into pieces and then [encode them into a TDateTime](http://www.delphibasics.co.uk/RTL.asp?Name=EncodeDateTime). To convert your month name to a month number you can iterate through the `LFormatSettings.ShortMonthNames` array, something like:

```
  String longMonth:= copy(S, 0, 3);
  for i := Low(LFormatSettings.ShortMonthNames) to High(LFormatSettings.ShortMonthNames) do
      if SameText(longMonth, LFormatSettings.ShortMonthNames[i]) then begin
          shortMonth:=FormatFloat('00', i);
          Break;
      end;
```

Comment: I get last system locale

gin
  if (ALCID <> gLCID) then
  begin
    gLCID := ALCID;
    gFormatSettings := TFormatSettings.Create(gLCID);
  end;
  Result := gFormatSettings;

Comment: Like I said, try modifying your question adding a sample code which is generating the error, just as the guy, I gave you as an example in the response above, did.

Comment: the best solution is use jvDateUtil.StrToDate*

Comment: Thanks for accepting my reply, but if you can put together a short explanation, what jvDateUtils is and how to use it, you can add a reply to your question and accept it as the `best answer`. It does not necessarily have to be someone else's answer, it is ok if you chose your own. The important thing is to learn and share with the others ;)

Answer (score 5):

Your format is completely non-standard (and almost incomprehensible), so can't be handled by the built-in Date/Time formatters.

You've designed your own format, so you need to write your own code to convert to and from it. 
This is nature's way of telling you not to use [wacky date and time formats](http://qurgh.wizage.net/hovpoh.htm)!